# Waterproof PCB pump driving stage

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, reliability, waterproof, humidity, fluid-pump

We are having issues with a small 12V DC pump which is used in a number of test systems in the field. The pump is powered by a standard DC power supply and integrates a small PCB driving stage, with speed measurement and motor supply circuits.

Some of the pumps from the field reported failure, after circa 1 year of use. Since the system is used for less than 8 hours a day and the MTBF of the pumps is in excess of 30.000 hours, we suspected that the failures could be caused by an external factor.

We verified the supply stage, but it looks like that there are no problems. We then opened one of the pumps and we found out that a part of the driving stage PCB was "corroded", some of the holding screws being totally rusty. The environment in which the pumps are used is exposed to moisture and this moisture can penetrate in the case and reach the PCB driving stage.

Is there a way to make the PCB totally waterproof or moisture proof in a fast and cheap way? Should we take specials regards with contacts and connections? How to properly isolate them?

Comment: Potting compound...

Comment: Potting compound would be my first choice, though there are spray-on conformal coatings that would probably help a lot too.  Be careful of thermal issues, as there will be less convection and thermals will change.  Material selection will have a big impact on thermal performance.

Comment: rubber glove sealed water tight with silica gel inside?. then factor temperature rise from thermal insulation.  brush motors? good luck.  Most plastics are still hydroscopic and still ingress moisture. Heat air and moisture accelerates rust.  But the cooler epoxy mask side was ok?

Comment: Conformal coating will help. Potting will help more. Boards not designed to be potted can be difficult to pot. You could also consider designing a waterproof closure (with O-rings and all).

Comment: It seems to me that you are jumping to a solution before you have identified the problem. Have you verified that the PCB actually failed, or are you just inferring that because the mounting screws are rusty?

Comment: MTBF != lifetime